# no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath" with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

**here the code for the "name" here the elements on google:**

```
 <div data-v-57d98753="" class="text-xxxs mb-02">AWP</div>
```

**I keep getting the no such element error and ive look into the site and no sign of iframe so its prob my code the error ive tried css selector, class name but still same error**

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import gspread
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd



url = 'https://csgoempire.com/withdraw#730'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(10)

skins = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='item')

time.sleep(20)

skin_list = []

for skin in skins:
   
    name = skin.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='.//*[@id="page-scroll"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]').text
    skin_name = find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='.//*[@id="page-scroll"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]').text
    condition = sfind_element(by=By.XPATH, value='.//*[@id="page-scroll"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span[1]').text
    float = find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='.//*[@id="page-scroll"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span[3]').text
    pourcentage = sfind_element(by=By.XPATH, value='.//*[@id="page-scroll"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button').text
    ski_item = {
        'name' : name,
        'skin_name' : skin_name,
        'condition' : condition,
        'float' : float,
        'pourcentage' : pourcentage
    }

    skin_list.append(ski_item)

df = pd.DataFrame(skin_list)
print(df)
```

**here ive tried with class name too but still same error**

```
name = skin.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value='text-xxxs mb-02')
skin_name = skin.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value='item__name text-xs font-bold')
condition = skin.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value='item__quality text-xxxs font-bold uppercase rounded-t px-2')
float = skin.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, value='item__name text-xs font-bold')
pourcentage = skin.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value='text-xxxs font-normal link has-tooltip')
```

**here is the error im getting for both**

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65291/devtools/browser/bcc3254c-0a6b-4d45-b05e-4c217b4d675a
[17348:7128:0524/180257.913:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:02:57.913] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1075 Getting Default Adapter failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\codes\bot\testbot3.py", line 30, in <module>
    name = skin.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value='text-xxxs mb-02')
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 763, in find_element
    return self._execute(Command.FIND_CHILD_ELEMENT,
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 740, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".text-xxxs mb-02"}
  (Session info: chrome=101.0.4951.67)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x005DB8F3+2406643]
        Ordinal0 [0x0056AF31+1945393]
        Ordinal0 [0x0045C748+837448]
        Ordinal0 [0x004892E0+1020640]
        Ordinal0 [0x0048957B+1021307]
        Ordinal0 [0x0047FAE1+981729]
        Ordinal0 [0x004A42C4+1131204]
        Ordinal0 [0x0047FA64+981604]
        Ordinal0 [0x004A4494+1131668]
        Ordinal0 [0x004B4682+1197698]
        Ordinal0 [0x004A4096+1130646]
        Ordinal0 [0x0047E636+976438]
        Ordinal0 [0x0047F546+980294]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00849612+2498066]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0083C920+2445600]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00674F2A+579370]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00673D36+574774]
        Ordinal0 [0x00571C0B+1973259]
        Ordinal0 [0x00576688+1992328]
        Ordinal0 [0x00576775+1992565]
        Ordinal0 [0x0057F8D1+2029777]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x779AFA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77CD7A7E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77CD7A4E+238]
```

Comment: Im trying to do a bot that can send all items on sale (Negative %) on a discord bot but i cant get past this

Comment: the page https://csgoempire.com/withdraw#730 does't exist

Comment: how so? because when i go to withdraw on the site the link is https://csgoempire.com/withdraw#730

Comment: the page is down now

Comment: what country are you from it might be blocked for you? since its a gambling site because its working for me right now im betting.

Comment: maybe is that, i from Uruguay

Comment: I'd avoid using these long path-based xpaths. Use something more specific (hopefully ids) to get most of the way there... there's a syntax issue with this line: driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='item') Seems like the 2nd part should be a single string... so maybe: driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'item')?  (don't know python, but by=by part seemed wrong too... maybe someone else will chime in there...)

Comment: for the by=By part i thought it was wrong too but im learning python rn and everywhere i got told to do that and yeah ive tried with class name instead of xpath since i dont like using xpath but i get the same error with name and css selector. and sadly no id's disponible.